# Fastest way to find the sign of different square

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, optimization, matrix

Given an image I  and two matrices m_1 ;m_2   (same size with I). The function f  is defined as: 
[image]
Because my goal design wants to get the sign of f . Hence, the function f  can rewritten as following:
[image]

- I think that second formula is faster than first formula because: It
  can ignore the square term
- It can compute the sign directly, instead of two steps in first equation: compute the f and check sign.

Do you agree with me? Do you have another faster formula for f

```
I =[16    23    11    42    10
    11    21    22    24    30
    16    22   154   155   156
    25    28   145   151   156
    11    38   147   144   153];

m1 =[0     0     0     0     0
     0     0    22    11     0
     0    23    34    56     0
     0    56     0     0     0
     0    11     0     0     0];

m2 =[0     0     0     0     0
     0     0    12    11     0
     0    22   111   156     0
     0    32     0     0     0
     0    12     0     0     0];
```

The ouput f is

```
 f =[1     1     1     1     1
     1     1    -1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1]
```

I implemented the first way, but I did not finish the second way by matlab. Could you check help me the second way and compare it

**UPDATE**: I would like to add code of chepyle and Divakar to make clearly question. Note that both of them give the same result as above f

```
function compare()
I =[16    23    11    42    10
    11    21    22    24    30
    16    22   154   155   156
    25    28   145   151   156
    11    38   147   144   153];

m1 =[0     0     0     0     0
    0     0    22    11     0
    0    23    34    56     0
    0    56     0     0     0
    0    11     0     0     0];

m2 =[0     0     0     0     0
    0     0    12    11     0
    0    22   111   156     0
    0    32     0     0     0
    0    12     0     0     0];

    function f=first_way()
        f=sign((I-m1).^2-(I-m2).^2);
        f(f==0)=1;

    end

    function f= second_way()
        f = double(abs(I-m1) >= abs(I-m2));
        f(f==0) = -1;

    end

    function f= third_way()
        v1=abs(I-m1);
        v2=abs(I-m2);
        f= int8(v1>v2) + -1*int8(v1<v2); % need to convert to int from logical
        f(f==0) = 1;

    end

disp(['First way : '  num2str(timeit(@first_way))])
disp(['Second way: '  num2str(timeit(@second_way))])
disp(['Third way : '  num2str(timeit(@third_way))])

end
```

`First way : 1.2897e-05 
Second way: 1.9381e-05 
Third way : 2.0077e-05`

Comment: I don't think your second formula is correct, because the square terms will change the sign of `v_i(x,y)` -- unless you know `I >= m_i` or something.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? The first equation or the second equation which is coherent with the title of the question but doesn't match up with the first equation?

Comment: @Divakar and angdaers3: Sorry, I mistaken the second equation. I update it. Let check it again. My goal is check the sign of equation f in equation 1 with fastest way. Because, we only consider the sign of f without the its real value, hence, we can reformula to make quickly computational time

Comment: @john2182 Add my Edited codes at the end into your benchmarking and also please increase the datasize? I would suggest something like this - `N = 5000;
I = randi(1000,N,N);
m1 = randi(1000,N,N);
m2 = randi(1000,N,N);
` if memory permits. Feel free to change the `N`, but try to keep that as a big number.

Comment: @Divakar: I check it again. Sorry that my expected result must conver 0 to 1. That mean the result f has only {1;-1}. So we need add the line  f(f==0) = -1; Do you have other equation to make faster? I proposed a equation 2 that extend from equation 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be comparable and might be a wee bit faster at times than the original approach -

```
f = sign(abs(I-m1) - abs(I-m2)) + sign(abs(m1-m2)) + ...
    sign(abs(2*I-m1-m2)) - 1 -sign(abs(2*I-m1-m2) + abs(m1-m2))
```

---

**Benchmarking Code**

```
%// Create random inputs
N = 5000;
I = randi(1000,N,N);
m1 = randi(1000,N,N);
m2 = randi(1000,N,N);

num_iter = 20;  %// Number of iterations for all approaches

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:100000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('------------------------- With Original Approach')
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter
    out1 = sign((I-m1).^2-(I-m2).^2);
    out1(out1==0)=-1;
end
toc, clear out1

disp('------------------------- With Proposed Approach')
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter    
    out2 = sign(abs(I-m1) - abs(I-m2)) + sign(abs(m1-m2)) + ...
           sign(abs(2*I-m1-m2)) - 1 -sign(abs(2*I-m1-m2) + abs(m1-m2));    
end
toc
```

**Results**

```
------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 1.751966 seconds.
------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 1.681263 seconds.
```

Comment: Thank Divakar. I compare the first way and second way by your implementation and chepyle. However, the fastest way is first way. Why is it fastest, algthough it must compute square result.

Comment: @john2182 If by first way, you mean `sign((I-m1).^2-(I-m2).^2)`, then it's giving you a wrong result, right? Also, make sure to choose a  sufficiently big data to time those! With these small datasizes, you won't be able to properly judge their performances!

Comment: No. The first way and second way give the same result. The first way computes the result of f and then check the its sign. However, it must compute square of matrix. For second way, we can compute the sign of f without square of matrix. With my observation, the second way must be faster. But matlab shown it is slower than first way

Comment: @john2182 `sign((I-m1).^2-(I-m2).^2)` doesn't give me the output that matches with `f` from the question. Could you check back again? Please tell us what must be the expected output!!

Comment: I shown the my expected output in my question. I think that the first method must be add one code as f(f==0) = -1;

Comment: let check update of my question. It will show clearly understand

Comment: Sorry. my expected result must conver 0 to -1. I check it agian

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with the accuracy of second formula, but for the sake of comparison, here's how I would implement it in matlab, along with a third approach to avoid squaring and the `sign()` function, inline with your intent.  Note that the matlab's matrix and sign functions are pretty well optimized, the second and third approaches are both slower.

```
function compare()
I =[16    23    11    42    10
    11    21    22    24    30
    16    22   154   155   156
    25    28   145   151   156
    11    38   147   144   153];

m1 =[0     0     0     0     0
    0     0    22    11     0
    0    23    34    56     0
    0    56     0     0     0
    0    11     0     0     0];

m2 =[0     0     0     0     0
    0     0    12    11     0
    0    22   111   156     0
    0    32     0     0     0
    0    12     0     0     0];

    function f=first_way()
        f=sign((I-m1).^2-(I-m2).^2);
    end

    function f= second_way()
        v1=(I-m1);
        v2=(I-m2);
        f= int8(v1<=0 & v2>0) + -1* int8(v1>0 & v2<=0);
    end

    function f= third_way()
        v1=abs(I-m1);
        v2=abs(I-m2);
        f= int8(v1>v2) + -1*int8(v1<v2); % need to convert to int from logical
    end

disp(['First way : '  num2str(timeit(@first_way))])
disp(['Second way: '  num2str(timeit(@second_way))])
disp(['Third way : '  num2str(timeit(@third_way))])

end
```

The output:

```
First way : 9.4226e-06
Second way: 1.2247e-05
Third way : 1.1546e-05
```

Comment: it seems you're into Image Processing - could you assist us open this dedicated group: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.